# How to databind the tooltip to part of a user control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I know this question has been asked many times before, I have found a few solutions here on line, but I could not make any of them work. I have a few elements on a custom control I have, and I want to put a bound tool tip on one of them. This is what I have so far.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DirectGraphicsControl.ColorBarView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:DirectGraphicsControl="clr-namespace:Windows.DirectGraphicsControl" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         SizeChanged="UserControlSizeChanged" MinWidth="95">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="80" x:Name="_mainDockPanel">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="_title" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,2"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,2,0,2"
                    x:Name="_bottomLabelsRegion" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <TextBlock x:Name="_unitName" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_mainDockPanel.Parent, Path=MyTooltip}" >
        <DirectGraphicsControl:DirectGraphicsControl x:Name="_directGraphicsControl"
                                                     MouseDoubleClick="HandleColorBarMouseDoubleClick" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <DirectGraphicsControl:DirectGraphicsControl.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </DirectGraphicsControl:DirectGraphicsControl.ToolTip>
        </DirectGraphicsControl:DirectGraphicsControl>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

and this is the code behind.

```
/// <summary>
    /// The tool tip text
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(Reflection.GetPropertyName<ColorBarView>(m => m.MyTooltip),
                                    typeof(string), typeof(ColorBarView));

    /// <summary>
    /// The tool tip text
    /// </summary>
    public string MyTooltip
    {
        get { return "Test from binding"; }
    }
```

The code behind property is only returning a hard coded string for now until I can actually get it working and then it will return the calculated value I would like it to. Currently on mouse over an empty box appears. When I add the text for the tooltip straight to the xaml it shows fine. This makes me think it cannot find the location of the binding.

I am very new to wpf so any suggestions would be great.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the dependency property to:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(Reflection.GetPropertyName<ColorBarView>(m => m.MyTooltip),
                                typeof(string), typeof(ColorBarView),new PropertyMetadata("Test Value") );
```

and the binding to:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_myControl, Path=MyTooltip}" >
```

Comment: That worked to remove the binding error found in the output window. Although I still do not get a value in the tooltip, it is just a blank box.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance tillerstarr, thank you for your replies... I have just tried that, and now I am back to getting an error in the output window: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=_myControl'. BindingExpression:Path=MyTooltip; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Comment: This gives a compile time error. "Unknown property 'Path' for type 'System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension. Line 18 Position 30."

Comment: It will compile now, but still has a problem finding the binding source: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=MyTooltip; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Comment: Still the same error: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=MyTooltip; DataItem=null; target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')  I am wondering if there is a fundemental problem with how the control is setup. I never imagined it would be so difficult. I like xaml and see how it could be powerful, but it would be great if there was some help from the IDE when locating the binding source.

Comment: Ah... it occurs to me that the elementName one probably worked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19116/discussion-between-tillerstarr-and-scott-lafoy)

Comment: I chose this answer a correct as this works in instances other then my project. I solved my problem with using a popup that was styled to look like a tooltip. Lots of thanks to tillerstarr for all his help.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Visual Studio output tab.  XAML Binding errors are printed out there, and it should be easy to spot the trouble from there.

Comment: I can see now I do have an issue with it not finding the binding. I am not sure how to solve the issue though. I would have thought there should be no problem in finding the code behind file to bind to a property. The following is the error from the output tab:  System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyTooltip' property not found on 'object' ''DockPanel' (Name='_mainDockPanel')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyTooltip; DataItem='DockPanel' (Name='_mainDockPanel'); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')